# Related to AWS S3 storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

when we choose Reduced Redundancy Storage or Infrequent Access storage  what action did AWS takes on their side. Are they using different type of storage to reduce the cost ?

Comment: I believe this answers all of your questions: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/reduced-redundancy/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to software development.

Comment: FYI S3 Standard is now actually cheaper than Reduced Redundancy Storage.

Answer (score 1):

AWS **does not reveal** details of the inner workings of their systems.

Instead, **they provide an API** and documented explanations of the services provided. This means that the internal methods can change, while still supporting the published API.

Answer (score 0):

**RRS S3 vs Standard S3:**

- *Durability:* As far as RRS is concerned, the reduced cost is due to inferior durability. Standard S3 provides 99.999999999% but RRS provides 99.99% durability. ie. On average, 1 object out of 10k(0.01%) objects per year may be expected to be lost.
- *Facility Tolerance:* Objects stored in Standard S3 is replicated across more facilities dhan RRS. Facility tolerance factor for RRS is 1 ie. It can withstand upto loss of 1 facility.
- *Performance:* Performance wise, RRS provied the same latency and throughput as that of Standard S3. If you data is critical and you need very high redundancy, it is recommended to go with Standard S3. Any non-critical and easily reproducible data can be stored in RRS.
- *Pricing:* The main advantage of RRS used to be the cost. Now that amazon has removed the cost advantage, there is not much difference in price between RRS S3 and Std S3(maybe some minute difference in some regions). Why pay the same price for lesser benefit? So you might actually prefer Std S3 in this aspect.  AWS might as well deprecate this feature as its of limited use now.

**Std Infrequent Access S3 vs Standard S3:**

- Performance, durability and availability wise, both the storage offer the same package.
- *Purpose:* The main difference between these two types depends on your need. As the name suggests, STD IA S3 is more suitable for less frequently accessed and long term data(But available and retrievable immediately when required). This is also one of the factor which differentiates Std IA S3 from glacier.
- *Pricing:* The pricing model is also defined according to the purpose of use. IA S3 offers low cost for storing objects (almost 50% of that of Std S3), but they charge you almost **double** for operations(put/copy/retrieve) when compared to Std S3. So if you are storing data in IA and accessing frequently, then you may end up paying more than if you had used Std S3. Database backups/DR data can be stored in IA. You don't access these data regularly, but it will be available immediately during critical scenarios. IA S3 also has a minimum object size of 128kb. Smaller objects will be charged for 128KB of storage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer madhukar but my question is what they use to reduce the cost of storage. As we can see the Durability of the object is same for infrequent and standred storage.

Comment: Akshay, They don't use inferior disks/drives for IA S3 to reduce cost. As I have mentioned, storage and performance wise, there is NO difference between IA S3 and Std S3. The cost difference is due to the difference in pricing model. While S3 is priced more for storing and less for accessing/retrieval, on the other hand IA S3 is priced less for storage and more for accessing. So if you just want to store data, IA S3 is cheaper.